# How to create a git repo that contain another repos references?

Tags: git, github, repository, versioning

I want to create a git Repo named `myExperiments` and add references to another github repos that i've created before (experiments projects). is Git submodules ideal for this kind of task? (there won't be any interactions between the referenced repositories).

Comment: What would be the usage of these "references"? Not sure to understand what you want to do..

Comment: Submodules are pretty much the only kind of reference that Git provide. I have a general motto now, "submodules are wrong" (meaning whatever the question is, submodules are the wrong answer) but in this case they might be only a little bit wrong. :-)